# React object spread (ES6) returned from map

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why is this working:

```
return elements.map((e)=> {return Object.assign({}, e, {selected:true})});
```

But this doesn't:

```
return elements.map((e)=> {...e, {selected: true}});
```

?

New to ES6 / Babel / React, have mercy.

UPDATE:
After moving to this (as suggested):

```
return elements.map(e => ({...e, selected: true }));
```

Get this error:
[image: unexpected token]

Though the spread is working elsewhere in the project:

```
        return [
            ...state,
            element(undefined, action)
        ]
```

Comment: Why is there no `return` in the second sample?

Comment: Spreading arrays is an ES6 feature, but spreading objects is an experimental proposed feature, so you'd have to enable it in Babel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An implicit return of an object from an arrow function should be wrapped in parens so the interpreter knows it's not a block.

So `return elements.map(e => ({...e, selected: true }));`

Also fixed the syntax for the selected property, it shouldn't be wrapped in brackets as azium pointed out.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Your unexpected token error is probably due to babel not supporting the proposed [object spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread). Array spread is es6. Using the plugin as in the answer below will solve this issue. My preferred way to include object spread is babel stage 0, as you also get other cool features like the `::` binding operator. Object spread is stage 2, so you could also use that if you don't want to include stages 1 and 0.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

Comment: Getting unexpected token for some reason (image attached on original question).

Comment: @Andy_D: it's a proposal, it is **not** part of ES7.

Answer (score 0):

The Object rest spread transform from the ES7 spec is not supported by Babel out of the box.  You'll need to use a plugin for that.

To install this plugin:

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread --save-dev
```

Then, add this to your .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

More info [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: Object spread is not part of ES7 (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/). It's a proposal.